# WP Events manager - Sending a email to users after event date

Tags: php, wordpress, email

We have been using the Events Manager Pro plugin for Wordpress for quite awhile. We were wondering if it would be possible to somehow be able to build something along the lines of "Send an email to the booked user once the event has completed" We would like to be able to send a "Thank you for attendance" E-mail to the people who booked the event.

If anyone has any idea of how to start building this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically just start programming?

Comment: Well yes I realise that, but I dont even know where to get started. I was hoping somebody could get me started

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there. You should prob. start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this works http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/automated-emails/#event-reminders (or) write a hook (CRON) how is handled in reminder, to meet ur requirements - have a custom logic to send a thanks note based on event end date and send to people who attended the event.